# MVC5 app hangs on starting application pool on IIS / Windows 2019 Server

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, debugdiag, windows-server-2019

I have an MVC5 application which uses various nugets (autofac, devextreme, automapper, entity framework).  I have 15 other MVC apps which also use all of these and work fine, but this one.....

Locally, either on IISExpress or IIS (Windows 10) it works fine.
When I deploy it to a Windows 2019, though, it hangs on startup.  It seems to be stuck in a memory-grabbing loop of some sort.  No http requests ever return and after 30 seconds running the Application Pool is using over 2GB of memory when locally it uses 200MB max.

Nothing is logged to EventLog.

I've added logging (serilog) and tracing to no avail....My startup code (global.asax / startup.cs) runs successfully and exits...and then nothing....The first http request hangs and all subsequent ones queue.

I've got no idea where to look next.  My final hail mary has been to install DebugDiag and create a dump - [the analysis of which is HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EhUK4Xw7WGGCgE4_7YS4hKcSRYX39af1/view?usp=sharing)

I'm no DebugDiag / Dump expert and all this is telling me is that every thread is waiting for Garbage Collection...Well...Not helpful...

Can someone please look at the dump analysis and tell me what I can do next / what is going on?

Comment: The analysis shows quite a bit related to Javascript Mimification.   This includes objects created and the thread which started GC (Thread 25) also doing Mimification work.

Comment: Thanks @Rich-Lang I will investigate bundles and _layout javascript further....

Answer (score 0):

So, this seemed to be resolved by increasing the amount of memory available to the server?!  Since I increased RAM it has never happened again......